# How to cerate local cahe for pip to use in LAN without internet?

Tags: python, caching, proxy, pip, devpi

I am trying to get pip install working in a machine without internet connection. I tried using three proxies(devpi-server, proxypypi and pypicache) in a server within same LAN, but with internet connection.

```
pip --no-cache-dir --trusted-host <serverip> install -i http://<serverip>:3141/root/pypi/+simple/ Flask
```

Pip ends up not using the proxy and try to collect packages directly from piwheels.org and files.pythonhosted.org and throws error(since the machine doesn't have internet connection).

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.piwheels.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/flask/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x75729ad0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Any solutions? Thank you

Comment: Please show the complete log of a `pip install -v <somepkg>`. You may also have options hidden in the `pip.conf`/`pip.ini`, e.g. `--extra-index-url` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the --proxy flag as the example here

```
sudo pip install --proxy=https://[username:password@]proxyserver:port somepackage
```

Comment: Thank you. I am also trying to create a PIP cache in the LAN since internet costly and not so good here.